# Sending An Email Attachment In Django (Production)

Tags: django, django-email

I am wanting to add an attachment to an email.

I am running this on a production server (I can do this in development).

I have successfully stored my static files in static_files using whitenoise and they display correctly on the page. I am trying to send one of these static files in this email.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
```

```
if form.is_valid():

    # have also tried '\\attachment\\test.pdf'
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT+'/attachment/test.pdf')

    try:
         msg = EmailMessage('subject', 'body', '#@#.#', '#@#.#')
                
         with open(file_path, 'rb') as attach_file:
             data = attach_file.read()
                    
         msg.add_attachment('test.pdf', data, 'application/pdf')

         msg.send()
```

Path to the file:

```
/home/project/project/static_files/attachment/test.pdf
```

This throws a 500 error.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you see what the error message is in your logs?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I didn't see your reply. I am also actually having difficulties getting my logs (even though I've read the docs). I will keep trying and if I can't get the logs working I'll create another thread. Thank you.